# How to find the average of just the user inputs above 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I'm trying to find the average of my results using only user inputed values above 0. I'm not sure how I would check the results in the array to find out which values are above 0 and exclude them from the calculation in swift.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var game1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var game2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var game3: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var series: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var average: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var high: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        guard
                let text1 = game1.text,
                let text2 = game2.text,
                let text3 = game3.text
        else { return }

        guard
                let game1Results = Int(text1),
                let game2Results = Int(text2),
                let game3Results = Int(text3)
        else { return }

        let gameResultsArray = [game1Results, game2Results, game3Results]
        let sumArray = gameResultsArray.reduce(0, +)
        let avgArrayValue = sumArray / gameResultsArray.count


        series.text = "\(sumArray)"
        average.text = "\(avgArrayValue)"
        if let maximumVal = gameResultsArray.max() {
        high.text = String(maximumVal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but the UITextField text property default value is an empty string so your `guard let text1 = game1.text` will never fail. You can safely unwrap the `text!` property

Comment: `filter` the array. And do you really want an integer average value?

Answer (score 1):

To filter out all values above 0 in an array, use the filter method. This will return a subset of your original array with all values passing the condition declared inside -

```
var demoArray = [-1, -8, 0, 1, 5 ,6]

var positiveArray = demoArray.filter { (item: Int) -> Bool in
  return item > 0
}

print(positiveArray) // [1, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter)
..

```
let sumArray = gameResultsArray.filter({$0 > 0})
let avgArrayValue = sumArray.reduce(0, +) / sumArray.count
```